# Finding missing votes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of proposals with unique IDs. I have another table with the votes on the proposals, linked with the proper proposal ID and the vote & username who voted per line.

Now I want to show one individual user on which proposals he did not vote yet. How do I do that, possibly in one query for one user?

Table schema:

proposals:

```
pr_id  proposal
1      proposal_text1
2      proposal_text2
3      proposal_text3
```

votes:

```
vote_id  pr_id  vote  user
1        1      yes   jack
2        1      no    jill
3        2      yes   jack
```

So in an example, I want to tell jill that she did not vote for proposal 2 and 3 yet.

Comment: How can we know without knowing the table schema?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor sorry, added the schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query for one user:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Proposals a
        LEFT JOIN Votes b
            ON  a.pr_id = b.pr_id
                AND b.user = 'jack'
WHERE   b.pr_id IS NULL
```

Query for displaying all user and the proposal he did not vote:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*, b.user
FROM    Proposals a
        CROSS JOIN Votes b
        LEFT JOIN Votes c
            ON  a.pr_id = c.pr_id
                AND b.user = c.user
WHERE   c.pr_id IS NULL
ORDER   BY b.user, a.pr_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo on both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/141aa/1)

Comment: Agree on the first one. Disagree on the last one. If a user hasn't voted on any proposal then you won't be returning all proposals for that user. +1/2 ?

Comment: TBH the first one works for me, not sure 100% what the second one does.

Comment: @uncovery you don't have table for the users.

Comment: @MostyMostacho if there are only two tables, `Proposals` and `votes`, where can you find the user that did not vote at all? If there is a `user` table, `Proposal` should be cross joined on that table.

Comment: That is exactly my point. The correctness of the second query relies on the existence of the `users` table which is very unlikely for it not to exist.

Comment: If you want for all users then you must have another table of Users for getting Unique users ...........!

Answer (score 1):

Using user 'jack' as an example:

```
select * 
from Proposals 
where not pr_id in (select pr_id from Votes where user='jack')
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2803/3)